# Netatmo Api - Need Hlep for if Temperature X then else

Tags: php, if-statement, temperature

I use the Netatmo api to Show Data of my Netatmo in my Private php Page.

Code:

```
$password="xxxx";
$username="xxxx";
// Daten vom Entwickler Account der Netatmo Seite
$app_id = "xxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxx";
// ------------------------------

$token_url = "https://api.netatmo.net/oauth2/token";
$postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'grant_type' => "password",
            'client_id' => $app_id,
            'client_secret' => $app_secret,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($token_url, false, $context);

$params = null;
$params = json_decode($response, true);

$url_devices = "https://api.netatmo.net/api/getstationsdata?access_token=".$params['access_token'];
$resulat_device = file_get_contents($url_devices);  
$array = json_decode($resulat_device,true);
```

Result:

```
echo $temp_aus;
```

(will show the Temperature outside in C )

I want to show the echo as Text.
So if its 10 C outside it shows text: its Cold outlide.

Any one have an idea?

Comment: What does it have to do with Java or HTML?

Comment: You're going to have to create an `if` or `switch` block to echo different strings based on the value of `$temp_aus`. How you do that is up to you.

Comment: HTML. 

Can anyone send a Example for it pls?

Answer (score 0):

You need an if

```
if($temp_aus<=10){
     echo "Its cold outside";
}
else{
     echo "Not its cold outside";
}
```